# ZSH tab completion of git commands is very slow. How can I turn it off?

Tags: unix, shell, git, zsh

If I type:

```
rm <TAB>
```

I'll see possible completions almost instantly.

However, if I type:

```
git rm <TAB>
```

It'll hang for several seconds if it's in a git repo, or fail to show any completions if I'm outside of a git repo.

How can I fix this behavior?

There's nothing in my .zshrc that looks like it has to do with git :-/

Comment: +1 This drives me so batty I've wired my brain to not hit `<TAB>` when using git.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I finally bothered to google this and came up with [this SO answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810485/877115) which worked perfectly for me. Add this to `.zshrc`:

```
__git_files () { 
    _wanted files expl 'local files' _files     
}
```

There's also a deep mailing list thread [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00490.html) about it explaining what `zsh` is doing to take so long.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm loading the following oh-my-zsh plugins: plugins=(git gitfast last-working-dir zeus). I loaded the above function after the plugins.

Comment: I had the same problem. Commenting to confirm success: on OSX 10.8.5, zsh 4.3.11, git 1.8.2, that .zshrc entry made all the difference. Without it, cpu regularly pinned at 100%. With it, tab completion seems about the same for git commands as any other. Thank you! :)

Comment: Make sure you put this command **before** your zsh plugins, otherwise you might end up with quick autocompletion, but errors once you try to actually run the git command.

Comment: While this solves the performance issue, it also results in a completion behaviour that doesn't know anything about modified/untracked/ignored files and will happily complete any file. While this may be fine or even preferrable for some users, I prefer the solution outlined in the other answer more convenient.

Comment: This worked for me on Big Sur.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another option: the official Git zsh completion: [git-completion.zsh](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/plain/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh). All you need to do is download that to `~/.zsh/_git`, and make sure it's in your fpath:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
```

I find it interesting that [this thread](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2011/msg00490.html) is mentioned in another response; I started that thread, and I wrote the official Git zsh completion as a result.

Answer (score 5):

None of the existing answers worked for me (where `git branch` autocompletion was taking ridiculously long).

Instead, the solution for me was switching from the default `git` plugin to `gitfast`.

I got this from a bit of a roundabout way, by first installing oh-my-zsh and then enabling the plugin. (There may be a better way to do this)

Steps:

1. Install `oh-my-zsh` via `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"` (based on instructions from [original repo](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master))
2. In your `~/.zshrc` file, replace the line `plugins=(git)` with `plugins=(gitfast)` to switch to the gitfast plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by using a combination of @FelipeC's answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028740/git-tab-completion-in-zsh-throwing-errors#28035917) from a similar Stack Overflow question.

When I only did what @FelipeC suggested, I then got the error mentioned in the referenced Stack Overflow question.  Following the instructions in the Stack Overflow answer fixed the error and made git auto completion far more responsive.